# PowerShell Sql Server Extended Events xml query value in between tags

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, extended-events

Given this sample xml, can anyone help me read the inputbuf?

```
<deadlock>   
<process-list>    
    <process id="123" taskpriority="123">     
        <inputbuf>  some random string like this   </inputbuf>    
    </process>    
</process-list>   
</deadlock>
```

I know that I can read the id & taskpriority like this:

```
$event.Fields["xml_report"].Value.XML.SelectNodes('//deadlock/process-list/process').id
```

They both give me "123". But I want the value between the inputbuf tags, I want to read the "  some random string like this   ". Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you parse the XML, but usually, there is property `InnerText`, which contains the text you want. For example, given that your XML is in string variable named `$xml`, you can use:

```
$node = $xml | Select-Xml -XPath "/deadlock/process-list/process/inputbuf"

Write-Host $xx.Node.InnerText
```

Comment: I haven't quite got that to work yet, it might be important for me to note that the xml is within a .xel file from Sql Server extended events, and I'm using `Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq.QueryableXEventData('C:\temp\deadlock.xel')` to import it